# does the order of condition in join affect query performance?

Tags: sql, join, db2

I'm writing some `SQL` and a question appeared in my mind.

`SQL` is like this:

```sql
select
    t1.column1,
    t2.column2
from
    table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
    on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA
where
    t1.name = 'kim kardashian'
```

Does the order in `on` clause affect `SQL` performance?

`on  t1.keyA = t2.keyA` and `on  t2.keyA = t1.keyA` is no difference?

Result of the `SQL` is same regardless the order.

Comment: I wonder moving the condition `t1.name = 'kim kardashian'` to JOIN ON condition, is that improve the performance? `ON  t1.keyA = t2.keyA AND t1.name = 'kim kardashian'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of conditions in the `on` clause should not affect performance.  Why not?  At a high level are three steps to SQL execution:

1. Parse the query
2. Construct and optimize the "executable" code
3. Execute the code

The second level optimizes the query and should take into account different methods of executing the query.  The join conditions are part of this optimization -- all at once.

In theory, it does not matter what the order of the `join`s are either, although in a very complex query, it could matter.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an inner join, only records matching on both sides of the join will be retained.  A logical consequence of this is that the join order does not affect the result set.  With most databases, the optimizer will therefore choose the join order with the best performance.  To your direct question, if you examine the query plan, you could very well see either `table1` or `table2` on the left side of the join.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Query optimizer will transform your code anyway. You better choose a convention and go with it. I prefer to write the ID of the joined table first, because it is more fluid for readers.